# How to parallelize multiple model-building procedures in sklearn

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, parallel-processing

Is there a way to parallelize multiple model-building procedures in scikit-learn? I know that I can use the `n_jobs` argument in both `GridSearchCV` and `cross_validate` to achieve some sort of parallelization **within one model building procedure**. However, I am running multiple model-building procedures in a for-loop with different input parameters and save the results in a list. Just as an example, suppose I have 15 free CPUs and I am using `n_jobs=5` in `cross_validate`. If I am not mistaken, that means that one single model-building procedure uses 5 CPUS. Now is there a way to already start the next 2 model-building procedures in my for-loop so I am using all 15 CPUS? Here's a dummy example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GridSearchCV, cross_validate

# load breast cancer data set
X,y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

# define different types of penalty strategies
# let's make a toy example and pretend we would be interested in
# running different penalty strategies (I use three times 'l2' here,
# but imagine these would be different)
penalty_types = ['l2','l2','l2']

# define output list where we add the results using different penalty strategies
nested_cv_scores_list = []

for penalty_type in penalty_types:
    
    # create a random number generator
    rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

    # z-standardize features
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    
    # use linear L2-regularized Logistic Regression as classifier
    lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=rng,penalty=penalty_type)
    
    # define parameter grid to optimize over (optimize C)
    lr_c = np.linspace(start=1,stop=16,num=11,endpoint=True)
    p_grid = {'lr__C':lr_c}
    
    # create pipeline
    lr_pipe = Pipeline([
        ('scaler',scaler),
        ('lr',lr)
        ])
    
    # define cross validation strategy
    cv = KFold(shuffle=True,random_state=rng)
    
    # implement GridSearch (inner cross validation)
    grid = GridSearchCV(lr_pipe,param_grid=p_grid,cv=cv)
    
    # implement cross_validate (outer cross validation)
    nested_cv_scores = cross_validate(grid,X,y,cv=cv,n_jobs=5)

    # append result to list
    nested_cv_scores_list.append(nested_cv_scores)
```

Is there a way to parallelize this for-loop?

Comment: If you set `n_jobs = -1`, it will use all available CPUs.

Comment: I know, but this will only affect the parallelization for one of my model-building procedures within my for-loop (so in my example: use 5 CPUs for 'l1' then 5 CPUs for 'l2' and finally 5 CPUs for 'elastic'). But I would like to parallelize the model-building procedures. A 'meta'-parallelization if you would want to call it that way.

Comment: I think `GridSearchCV` is capable of carrying out all of these calculations in parallel without having to creating a `for-loop`. You just need to pass'em as usual. Unless ya really have specific reason for the `for-loop` (which I failed to see), then you can create your own `GridSearchCV` and use a multi-processing (i.e. pool) approach inside the `for-loop`.

Comment: Of course, the script above is just a simplified example. I have systematic/fixed differences between my model-building procedures (e.g. in my example I pretend to use three different penalty strategies), that I would like to compare. This is what the for-loop is for. I do not want to optimize those as hyperparameters as I want to make sure that certain parameters stay constant within my model-building procedures ("Run three nested-cross validations with fixed parameters a, b, c"). I am not sure how `GridSearchCV` can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joblib.parallel` is made for this job! Just put your loop content in a function and call it using `Parallel` and `delayed`

```
from joblib.parallel import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GridSearchCV, cross_validate

# load breast cancer data set
X,y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

# define different types of penalty strategies
# let's make a toy example and pretend we would be interested in
# running different penalty strategies (I use three times 'l2' here,
# but imagine these would be different)
penalty_types = ['l2','l2','l2']

# define output list where we add the results using different penalty strategies
nested_cv_scores_list = []

# put rng-seed outside of loop so that not all results are the same
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

def run_as_job(penalty_type, X, y):

    # create a random number generator
    

    # z-standardize features
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    
    # use linear L2-regularized Logistic Regression as classifier
    lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=rng,penalty=penalty_type)
    
    # define parameter grid to optimize over (optimize C)
    lr_c = np.linspace(start=1,stop=16,num=11,endpoint=True)
    p_grid = {'lr__C':lr_c}

    .... # additional calculation that is missing in the example
    .... # e.g. res = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, n_jobs=2)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(run_as_job)(penalty_type) for penalty_type in penalty_types)
```

for more usage options have a look at [joblib: Embarrassingly parallel for loops](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html)

Comment: I already thought about this but wasn't sure if this is possible? How is `Parallel(n_jobs=2)...` (the "most outer loop") interacting with `cross_validate(...,n_jobs)` as they both define the number of CPUs to use? So for example in your script you use `Parallel(n_jobs=2)`...If I get the docs right that should define that two iterations are running in parallel each of them occupying one CPU. Doesn't this automatically mean that everything that is nested within that is restricted to only one single CPU which would contradict with `cross_validate(n_jobs=5)`?

Comment: Parallel will spawn two processes, each running the function once. Within this function `cross_validate(n_jobs=5)` will spawn another 5 processes. So in total there will be a maximum of 10 processes running. You'll have to try out a bit how to utilize all cores optimally, sometimes `2x5` will run slower than `5x2`, depending entirely on how well different sub-tasks parallelize, and what the overhead of function calls is. Parallelization in Python is sometimes a bit tricky, as `threading` only runs on a single CPU due to the GIL. Only spawning processes will utilize all CPUs.

Comment: This does exactly what `GridSearchCV` does with `n_jobs=2`!

Comment: @Yahya why do you think that? `Parallel(n_jobs=5)` spawns 5 processes, and `GridSearchCV(X,y,n_jobs=2)` spawns another 2 processes each, so it's more. Depending on how many folds you are doing this approach makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Firstly, everything in your code (and in the OP's example) is very lightweight. Hence, the only thing that would require multi-processing is trying different parameters, and that's what `GridSearchCV` does in parallelized way without the need for the outer `for-loop`. Besides, if OP wants to check the meta results for every model with different parameters hold fixed, they can via `GridSearchCV` too.  Finally, the resources on any machine are limited, therefore, throwing all these processes almost surely result in throttling of high performance computers CPU or GPU.